# Is it safe to send 8-bit emails?

Tags: email, smtp, email-client, 8-bit, quoted-printable

I would like to know if it is safe to send emails with 8-bit characters or if it is still needed to use quoted-printable or base64 encoding.

The [8BITMIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_SMTP#8BITMIME) extension is now 20 years old. Are there SMTP servers or mail clients that still are not 8-bit clean? Is there any impact on email deliverability when sending 8-bit emails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not find any numbers but it looks like it is now quite safe to send emails with 8-bit body. But since the big players like Gmail still encode emails there might be some servers that still are not 8-bit clean.

However while sending an email with an 8-bit **body** might be safe, sending it with 8-bit **headers** is not.

[RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822) which was the standard until late 2008 [prohibited non-ASCII characters in headers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-7).
[RFC 6532](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6532) proposed a standard for 8-bit headers but it is quite recent (2012) and does not seem widely implemented yet.

So sending unencoded 8-bit emails is currently not safe.

Answer (score 1):

There are still SMTP servers that haven't been updated to support 8BITMIME, so yes, you still need to check for the extension.

Comment: I'm basing this on experience, not on any link. I've been working on email software since 1999.